# Loop discord bot

Tags: loops, discord, bots

I try to do a loop for rename my friends with a bot on discord but nothing to do :( Nothing works, I try to find in this forum or others but nothing :c.

Here is the code that I try

```
@Salcy.command()
async def forcenick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    ok = 1
    while ok == 1:
        await member.edit(nick=nick)
        sleep(5)
```

But when I want to do another command, it stops the loop :/

PS : I'm french, sorry if my english is bad :/

Comment: Why are you looping the nickname change? Running it once _should_ change the nickname right?

Comment: @Josie I try to do this so my friends can't change

Comment: Ah, okay. The thing is, running a loop keeps the thread occupied. In order to run the next command, it needs to stop that loop. I'd take a look at multi-threaded programming to get the bot to run commands on new threads, or something of the like. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: oh ok, thanks for your help ! ^^

Comment: Of course, HTH!